# Hide navigation bar in NavigatorIOS component (react-native) doesn't work after RN update

Tags: react-native, navigationbar, navigator-ios

I had recently upgraded my react native project from ~0.28 to the most recent version (0.43.2) and for some reason my navigation bar no longer hides for me.

Here is the code (it is sitting in a TabBarIOS component):

```
    <TabBarIOS.Item
      selected={this.state.selectedTab === 'home'}
      title='Home'
      icon={require ('./Icons/IconImages/HomeTabIcon.png')}
      onPress={
        () => this._tabPressed('home')
      }>
      <NavigatorIOS
        style={styles.container}
        ref="nav"
        interactivePopGestureEnabled={false}
        initialRoute={{
          title: 'Home',
          component: HomeNavigationController,
          navigationBarHidden: true, //this does nothing now
          showTabBar: false, //this is to hide the bottom tabBar
          passProps: {
            ...
          },
        }}/>
      </TabBarIOS.Item>
```

Adding it outside `initialRoute` also does not work:

```
          <NavigatorIOS
        style={styles.container}
        ref="nav"
        interactivePopGestureEnabled={false}
        initialRoute={{
          title: 'Home',
          component: HomeNavigationController,
          showTabBar: false,
          passProps: {...},
        }}
        navigationBarHidden={true} // does not work
        />
```

Comment: Your code, second version, is working for me (0.43). What is in styles.container ?

Comment: Yes it does indeed work after starting over and re-adding my components.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, after trying to isolate the problem by stripping out everything and reducing it to its most basic form, I realized that it the problem wasn't in any code that I could find.

I initialized a new project from scratch and then re-added all my components and now it works just fine.